# Nginx vhost config issue

Tags: magento-1.8, development, nginx, shopping-cart

I am migrating my store from apache to Nginx due to memory and performance concerns. I configured vhost file for http and https, but somehow I am not able redirect http://www.domain.com/admin to https://www.domain.com/admin.

On login window, it prompts me to login and I was able to login successfully, but it doesnt redirect from http to https before login. After login it redirects to https without any certification issue.

Certificate is valid as I am able to browse normal pages in https by typing in manually.

Here is my config file:

```
server {
listen      80;
server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
root        /var/vhost/www/domain.com/public_html/;
index index.html index.php;

access_log /var/vhost/www/domain.com/logs/access_log;
error_log /var/vhost/www/domain.com/logs/error_log;
listen 443  ssl;
ssl_certificate /var/vhost/www/domain.com/ssl/www_domain_com_ee.crt; 
ssl_certificate_key /var/vhost/www/domain.com/ssl/domain.com.np.key;
ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
}
location /app/                       { deny all; }
location /includes/                  { deny all; }
location /lib/                       { deny all; }
location /media/downloadable/        { deny all; }
location /pkginfo/                   { deny all; }
location /report/config.xml          { deny all; }
location /var/                       { deny all; }

location /var/export/ {
    auth_basic              "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file    htpasswd;
    autoindex               on;
}
location  /. {
    return 404;
}

location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
}

location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires off;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d;=$1 last;
rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d;=$1 last;

location /lib/minify/ {
    allow all;
}
gzip on;
#gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_min_length  1000;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types       text/plain application/xml text/css text/js application/x-javascript;
```

}

Would really appreciate your help smile

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The trick would be to redirect all http requests to https with a `return 301 https://www.domain.com`

Check the [Poodle proof, bulletproof Nginx SSL configuration](https://t37.net/a-poodle-proof-bulletproof-nginx-ssl-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running the backend under a subdomain (e.g. www.website.com/manage)

at which point you can create a vhost to listen for this that looks like this:

```
    server {
listen 80;
server_name manage.website.com;
return 301 https://manage.website.com;
}

server {
listen 443;
##SSL SETTINGS HERE##
server_name manage.website.com
#REST OF PRE-EXISTING VHOST HERE, PHP exection etc.#

}
```

that would do the trick, obviously replace the hash's with snippets of your existing frontend vhost.